# How can I send email with a custom "from" address on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to send email from an address I control, but currently this means that I have to create a Google Account for it and then add it as a developer. Given that the domain is hosted on Google Apps, there's already an address like that, aliased to me. Google won't let me create a new account with that email, so I'm stuck.

Is there a simple way to prove I own the address and send mail from it, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The From address needs to be registered as an admin of the application (or the address of the logged-in user, which obviously doesn't apply here).

Comment: Or it needs to be one of the app's own addresses.

Comment: I could live with that, but I can't find a way to register this address as a Google account and, consequently, as a developer... @Nick Johnson, are there any plans to simpify this by only requiring verification of the address?

Comment: If the domain is hosted on Google Apps, it's already a Google account.

Comment: @Wooble, not if it's an alias, which mine is. The email address is also an alias, so it fails twice.